# Android Espresso not working with Multidex gives "No tests found"

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-multidex

My Espresso tests were running until I had to support multidex.

My build.gradle, I have

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 23
multiDexEnabled = true

testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"


androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'

dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        incremental true
    }
```

### Test1AuthenticationEspressoTest

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class Test1AuthenticationEspressoTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<WelcomeActivity> mActivityRule = new  ActivityTestRule(WelcomeActivity.class);

}
```

Here is the Error I get

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in
>   com.livestrong.tracker.test.Test1AuthenticationEspressoTest

Any help will be appreciated. Any one has espresso working with multidex ?

Comment: so if you delete 'multiDexEnabled = true' you would be able to test, right? Think about new module in your project with its own Gradle file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34590175/588532

Comment: Well it started working when I changed the test runner to         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but none of the changes you made seem to fix it. This blows.

Answer (score 41):

I was having this same problem and it turns out you need to build a custom runner that enables MultiDex and extends from the AndroidJUnitRunner.  You then need to set that runner as your testInstrumentationRunner in the build.gradle, and as your runner in your run configuration.  There is no need to modify the test class (keep the `@RunWith(AndroidJunit4.class)`).

Here's a step-by-step of what to do:

1. Create a class for your custom runner:

   ```
   package com.bla.bla.bla;  // your package

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
   import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner;

   public class CustomTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner
   {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle arguments)
       {
           MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
           super.onCreate(arguments);
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your build.gradle, set the runner to your custom runner:

   ```
   android {
       // ...
       defaultConfig {
           // ...
           testInstrumentationRunner "com.bla.bla.bla.CustomTestRunner"
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your run configuration, [make sure the instrumentation runner is also set to the same runner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSzNa.png). **Note:** This step should not be required on Android Studio 3.x and maybe also some previous versions. This option does not exist anymore.

Using the above, I was able to run Espresso tests on our multi-dex enabled app.

I should note that many other posts on the net regarding this topic, suggest setting your runner to `com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner` and exculde some dependencies in `com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1` in your build.gradle.  That solution appears to no longer be the case and doesn't work as of gradle 1.5.0.  If you have any of that stuff set, then it'll prevent the above from working.  See the comments in [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056075/which-package-for-multidextestrunner-android-support-multidex-or-com-android-te) for more information.

Comment: Your answer were promissing, but I still get an issue : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: This answer should be ACCEPTED.

Comment: This is basically working for me, except for one thing: when I run this way any of my code that references classes in jars pulled in from the 'libs' directory (loaded like so `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`) will fail with `NoClassDefFoundError`. Everything else works fine.

Comment: This doesn't work.  In addition, your code is exactly what's in MultiDexTestRunner, so if this code did work it wouldn't be necessary.