# 'transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebugAndroidTest' task fails when android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner specified

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I'm trying to run an espresso test on MultiDex app and am failing with the below error

> Error:Execution failed for task > :transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebugAndroidTest'.
>   java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper > '-keep' options?

Here's the relevant section in my build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        //      Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions {
            jumboMode true
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
```

I do have a workaround which is to:

1. comment out 'testInstrumentationRunner' line
2. Build the test
3. Uncomment the line
4. Run the test

This seems to work, but I need to re-do this any time I'm changing my test code, which is a major pain.

Could fine similar error online, but nothing specific to my case...

I am building using Android studio

Answer (score 0):

My reputation doesn't allow me to comment, so will write as an answer:

Exactly the same workaround works for me:

1. Commenting the string with 'testInstumentationRunner'
2. Building tests. There will be an exception that Instrumentation Runner is not found
3. Uncomment the string
4. Run the test

> UPD: This solution worked for me, though the question there is about different problem:
>
> [Android Espresso not working with Multidex gives "No tests found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645537/android-espresso-not-working-with-multidex-gives-no-tests-found)