# Multi-module MultiDex project won't run tests after update to android gradle plugin 2.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation

I have project with multiple modules, all of which are configured to build with `multiDexEnabled true`. All of these modules have instrumentation test packages that are configured to run JUnit4 tests with `MultiDex` enabled per this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35214158/736963 EXCEPT for one of the modules. One of the modules is configured to use `testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"` (and hence has no JUnit4 tests) because it depends on a DLL that just *will not load* with the JUnit4 test runner. (If anyone knows the solution to that one, that's great! But that's not the problem I'm reporting here...)

This configuration has been working fine until I just attempted to update to **android gradle plugin 2.3.0**. Now when I run tests for the module using the JUnit3 `MultiDexTestRunner`, I see this:

```
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'
Empty test suite.
```

And in the console this (truncated to the useful bit):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.redacted.test/com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.redacted.test-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.redacted.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.redacted.test-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.redacted.test-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.redacted.test-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.redacted.test-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.intuit.paymentshub.test-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.intuit.paymentshub.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.intuit.paymentshub.test-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.intuit.paymentshub.test-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.intuit.paymentshub.test-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.intuit.paymentshub.test-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

So I'm stuck on the earlier Android Gradle Plugin until I can resolve this (or the DLL problem, though I'm less hopeful on that one since it has *never* worked.)

Comment: And yes, I did read the release notes for 2.3.0, and tried running `cleanBuildCache`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this problem went away after updating the tooling. Currently running android for gradle 2.3.3 with buildTools 26 and this problem is gone.